# Does Mutual Information by the power of 3 for the numerator really exist?

Tags: statistical-significance, mutual-information, corpus-linguistics

I am currently trying to measure collocational strength using Mutual Information (MI). MI gives an edge for exclusive and infrequent words. As stated by Brezina (2018), in measuring collocational strength, one may use Mutual Information with this following formula:

Log2(O11/E11),

where:

O11 = frequency of collocation

E11 = expected frequency of collocation

In addition to the MI formula stated above, the author also states the MI3 formula, which is almost similar to MI, but it gives the O11 a power of three. This formula gives an edge for exclusive and frequent words. The formula is as follows:

Log2(O11^3/E11)

Can anybody explain to me what is this power of three in the MI3 is called? I tried to find that exact formula online but to no extent. Is it a general practice in statistics? And why exactly giving a power of three to result in such change, that is, making the MI more sensitive to frequent and exclusive collocations?

I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance!

Reference:

Brezina, V. (2018). Statistics in corpus linguistics: A practical guide. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: If you're going to refer to existing work, it's beneficial to include the complete citation.

Comment: Brezina, V. (2018). Statistics in corpus linguistics: A practical guide. Cambridge University Press. Here you go @AryaMcCarthy :)

Comment: Generically, "3" is a *weight.*  You can see this from the fundamental identity $$\log(x^\mu/y^\lambda)=\mu\log x - \lambda \log y$$ where, as usual, the weights appear as coefficients in a linear combination.